# creating dynamic html links with data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to create dynamic html links with data from *AIPIFLICKR*, I get the data from **flickr** so I just need to make the links with invisble date from `author_id` and when clicked on I need to get this in JS back my code (it works but not the links):

```js
var output = "";
$.each(flickrresponse.items, function(index, value) {
  //console.log(index);
  output += '<div> <a href="">' +
    value.author + '</a><figure><img src="' +
    value.media.m + '" alt="' +
    value.title + '" title="' +
    value.title + '" /><figcaption>' +
    value.author + '</figcaption></figure></div>';
})
$('#output').html(output)
```

and then I need somthing like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('a').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    extrafeatures(datafromlink);
  });
});
```

Comment: <a href="javascript:;"> maybe help.

Comment: @Roy That is a horrible idea. The preventDefault works the same - he just needs to delegate: `$('#output').on("click","a",function() { ... });`

Comment: @mplungjan <a href=""> will return error on HTML validators... so.. is horrible idea?

Comment: He can add "javascriptneeded.html" or "#" instead of that ugly thing - anyway that was not his problem

Comment: Yep, but not leave it emtpy.

Comment: Sure - but that was not his problem. Only the validator will complain, not the browser.

Comment: Is `author_id` in `value`? If so, add it to e.g. `data-author='value.author_id'` and get that in the `click` function.

Comment: @Arg0n oke I will try this! thanks for the answers.

Comment: @Arg0n Oke i can set the data but i can't retrieve it?                             'var test =function (test)
{

    console.log(test);

}
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('form').on('submit', flickrQuery);
    $('a').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        test($(this).data('author'));
    });
});'

Comment: E.g. `$('<div data-author="1">').data('author'); //1`.